# Using sed on multiple files in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a sed script to insert a line before a keyword "MYWORD" found in the file.  My script is the following:

```
sed -e '/MYWORD/ i\MY NEW LINE TO BE INSERTED' <inputFilename >outputFilename
```

Since this will only occur on just one file how can I change my script to have this insert occur on every file in the directory?

Comment: Are you saying that your example code actually *works* on a single file?

Answer (score 1):

As nosid said, you can use the `-i` option to edit a file in place.  Read the man page in YOUR operating system to determine exactly how to use `-i`.  Then you can wrap sed in a little bit of shell script to identify and act on the file:

```
for this in foo*.txt; do
  sed -i'' -e 'your-sed-script' "$this"
done
```

That said, I'm not sure your insert method will work, or at least work reliably.  I tested in FreeBSD and OS X, and it didn't work at all.  My normal strategy for inserting lines is to use awk, instead.  Thus (for example):

```
for this in foo*.txt; do
  awk '/MYWORD/{print "Extra line of text goes here."} 1' "$this" > "$this.$$"
  mv "$this.$$" "$this"
done
```

The awk line here searches for /MYWORD/ (an extended regular expression, whereas `sed` defaults to basic regular expressions).  If it finds it, it first prints the "Extra" text.  Then, the "1" evaluates as a "true" that will also print the current line.  The effect is to insert the "Extra" text on the line before MYWORD.

Note that this isn't a *good* script.  It's wasteful, piping and renaming files that haven't been modified.  You could improve it by choosing to "mv" the temp file depending on an exit value from awk, or you could use `cmp` to determine if the file had changed, then clean up leftover tempfiles, etc...  But it gets the point across.